# javascript missing a url parameter during redirection

Tags: javascript, php

my website has an option of country like for different country the website layout is different. it is running on the basis of sessions if session is not set the user will be redirected to index to select a country then will be redirected from the page where he originally came from. here's the code

my `session_check_client.php` file that is included in every file except index

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['country']))
{
    $actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
    header("location:index.php?return_uri=$actual_link");
}
?>
```

now what happens is when i go back to home page i wanna check whether this requested has some return parameter or just user has visited he website for the first time. there are two button for two countries of which i am showing the code.

```
function canada(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'ajax_country.php?country=canada',
        success: function (data) {
            var $_GET = <?php echo json_encode($_GET);?>;
            if($_GET){
            //window.location.href=$_GET['return_uri'];
            alert($_GET['return_uri']);
            }
            else {
                window.location.href = "home.php";
            }
        }
    });
}
function us(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'ajax_country.php?country=us',
        success: function (data) {
            var $_GET = <?php echo json_encode($_GET);?>;
            if($_GET){
                //window.location.href=$_GET['return_uri'];
                alert($_GET['return_uri']);
            }
            else {
                window.location.href = "home.php";
            }
        }
    });
}
```

now the problem is when i am alerting the value of `$_GET['return_uri']` it is giving me a false value

e.g my return_uri value is `http://localhost/interfold/products2.php?category=Aprons&id=57725599688` it actually shows the whole value in return_uri in index page like `http://localhost/interfold/products2.php?category=Aprons&id=57725599688` but when is get the url value using javascript it is onlye giving me the value `http://localhost/interfold/products2.php?category=Aprons` it is missing the $ and afterwards parts!!! any recommendations?

Comment: On a sidenote, you should really prevent duplicate code by merging the canada() and us() function into one function with one possible parameter for the country

Comment: totally agreed!!! i will re modify it once issue is resolved

Comment: Do you really need the $actual_link to be a $_GET paramter? Could it also be another solution?

Comment: there are other solution like using session etc but i find it more professional, alot of websites use this idea and its a good one

Comment: What I mean is, instead of placing a URL parameter, you could also directly create a JS-variable, such as: `var actual_link = "<?php echo $actual_link; ?>";`. Then in the AJAX success callback that would look like `window.location.href = actual_link`. Do you think that is a workable solution?

Comment: lets suppose i made a variable in fileB.php how would i get a js variable from fileB.php to index.php? that is why i am sending the value in the  URL as parameter so that i can access it from index.php

Comment: Not a best practice, but you could try a global variable: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_superglobals.asp

Comment: well i can't use a global variable inside JavaScript the actually return_uri is made from super globals but what do i do in javascript

Comment: Then if the return_uri only contains super globals data, then please see my answer:

Answer (score 0):

Since you are only using super global variables, you can directly print a JS variable above the function you are describing:

```
var actual_link = "<?php echo "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"; ?>";

function postCountry( country ){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'ajax_country.php?country=' + country,
        success: function (data) {
            if(actual_link){
                //window.location.href=actual_link;
                alert(actual_link);
            }
            else {
                window.location.href = "home.php";
            }
        }
    });
}

postCountry('us');
postCountry('canada');
```

Comment: nops!!! there are two files lets suppose i am comming from FileA.php to index.php i am setting my super global at FileA.php then returning the url to index,php what you are doing is getting the url in index.php which in incorrect